# Determine output filter using the bode approximation

Tags: filter, communication, modulation, bode-plot

Given that the carrier frequency Fc and modulation input frequency Fm are known, how would I use the bode approximation to determine an output filter, if the carrier frequency component must receive less than 35dB interference from the other frequencies?

Comment: I suggest you draw a picture of your question (phone pic is OK). It will both help you explain where you are stuck and others help you

Comment: Unfortunately I can't but what I've described is very similar to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this [website](http://www.onmyphd.com/?p=bode.plot)

There is a slope of -20 dB/decade per each pole. So you calculate how many decades there are between Fc and the frequency in question (x = log10(f/Fc)), and you add as my poles as needed. Note that if you place the pole at Fc you will add a 3dB drop at Fc. So you will need a 38dB attenuation on your interferent frequency instead of 35dB.